# fprintf ignore ^M carriage returns

Tags: c, printf, line-endings

I have my fopen set up like this. I have tried my fopen with both "t" and without "t". For some reason my fprintf is printing out ^M which are carriage returns. How do I stop frpintf from doing this? I want to just  use the normal new line character.

```
FILE *outputfp;
// +5 to have space for .txt and terminator 
char *fname = calloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 5, sizeof(fname[0])); 
strcpy(fname, argv[1]);
strcat(fname, ".lst");
outputfp = fopen (fname, "w");
//printf("Above error message\n");
if (outputfp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
    return 1;
}
fprintf(outputfp, "hello\n");
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character
http://www.pixhost.org/show/4770/21527928_cr.jpeg

I'm using Fedora and I compile this with gcc

**Update:**

```
    if((int)line[0] == 46)
    {
        //printf("You have a period \n");
        //printf("%s", line);
        for(i = 0; i < 80; i++)
        {
            //fprintf(outputfp,"%c", line[i]);
            if (isprint((unsigned char)line[i]) || isspace((unsigned char)line[i]))
             { 
             printf("%c", line[i]);
             //fprintf(outputfp, "\n Print something \n");
             fprintf(outputfp,"%c", line[i]);
             }

            //printf("%c", line[i]);
            //printf("  %d %c  ", line[i], line[i]);
        }
        //fprintf(outputfp, "\n ");
        //printf(" ------------------------\n");
        memset(line, 0, 80);
        comment_flag = 1; 
    }

        //sscanf(line, "%s %s %x", label, mneumonic , &start_address);
        //printf("start_address %d \n", start_address);
        printf("%x %s %s %s %x\n", start_address, label, mneumonic, operand, start_address);
        fprintf(outputfp, "%x %s %s %s %x\n", start_address, label, mneumonic, operand, start_address);
```

It actually looks like this is the line it doesn't like. I wanna cycle through my whole array before it prints a new line character.

```
fprintf(outputfp,"%c", line[i]);
```

**Update:**

```
char line[80] = {0};
while(fgets(line, 80, input) != NULL)
```

Comment: give an example of what does it output, what is your desired output?

Comment: Perhaps try `fopen(fname, "wb");` instead of just `"w"`?  I'm not sure how you got it into this mode.

Comment: Just a new line character. It outputting both new line characters and carriage returns

Comment: @Michael It does the same thing.

Comment: Michael's suggestion is the only thing you can do from a C program. What is your operating system environment? What is your compiler version?

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC) 
Fedora

Comment: As Matt noted, you are not printing to your opened file.

Comment: @jxh I added an frpintf.

Comment: Please embed the image directly into your post rather than posting a link.

Comment: @jxh How I have never done that before? Can you tell me or do it for me? Whatever is easier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51312/discussion-between-cokedude-and-jxh)

Comment: @Kevin , it does do what he thinks it does (assuming his computer uses ASCII)... what do you think it does?

Comment: @MattMcNabb lacking the input code and given the cast to int and integer literal I assumed he was trying to check for a string containing "46". Actually reading the following code I see he probably does intend to check for a period.

Comment: @Kevin Yes your right I was looking for a period.

Comment: You should really use a character literal: `if (line[0] == '.')`. It's much more clear what you intend. And a cast isn't necessary either way.

Answer (score 1):

`"t"` is the default. If you want binary mode then open with `"wb"`.

A text stream (the default) may perform various conversions between the disk file and what your C program sees; a binary stream is meant to have a 1-1 character mapping (although this is all implementation-defined of course).

**Update:** Since you are working in Linux, probably there is no problem with text or binary mode.

Based on your output screenshot, it seems that you actually wrote a `\r` to your file. The first line doesn't have one. It'd help if you actually show the code which generates that output. Perhaps you are reading those lines in from a file which has `\r\n` line endings.

**Update #2:** It turns out that the `\r` characters are coming from a file that is being read in and then being output verbatim after passing through a filter `if (isprint((unsigned char)line[i]) || isspace((unsigned char)line[i]))`.

The `isspace` function lets through all of `" \t\n\v\f\r"`. You'll need to modify this check; perhaps you could also block out `\r` and `\f`; or alternatively, stop using `isspace` and just check for `' '` `'\t'`, and reinstate your output of `"\n"` after the loop.

Comment: I'm using Fedora and I compile this with gcc. Yes you are write with your fprintf statement.

Comment: I show my print statements. It doesn't seem to like it when I print through my array.

Comment: Where is `line` coming from in your code? I presume the block starting `line[0] == 46` corresponds to the output `. tests pc forward addressing`, so probably `line` already has the `\r` character in it.

Comment: line is my character array that gets filled by fgets as I read through a file.

Comment: I used vi show the hidden characters that I'm reading. It all ends in $ which are new line characters.

Comment: `vim` knows about Windows text files.  Try hex-dumping the file (`od -Ax -t x1 filename`) . Updated my post again

Comment: Is there a way to make the hex dump more readable? It turns into a big jumbles mess. I tried to compare it to an ascii table but everything is out of order.

Comment: Look for `0d 0a` in the output. That would be `\r\n`. You can use `more` to page it.